# Non-resident alien: Why did I pay no tax on dividend income?

Tags: united-states, taxes, dividends, non-resident, bond-etf

I have a US stock brokerage account, and I am a non-resident alien. From my understanding, dividend income of non-resident aliens is taxed at a flat 30% rate (assuming no applicable tax treaties). I am currently resident in a jurisdiction with no applicable tax treaties with the US.

- In June 2020, I bought 10 shares of VTIP (Vanguard Short-Term Inflation-Protected Securities ETF).
- In October 2020, I was paid a dividend of $2.80 of which 30% ($0.84) was withheld.
- In December 2020, I was paid a dividend of $3.33 of which 30% ($1.00) was withheld.

Surprisingly, I got a $0.84 and $1.00 refund in February 2021. I checked the Form 1042-S provided by the stock brokerage firm, and noticed that I was somehow exempted from all tax.

Can someone explain what happened? Why was my tax rate 0%?

---

UPDATE:

I now understand the situation after reading all these pages:

- [What are the taxation rules for US non-resident aliens with respect to qualified dividends?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/126696/what-are-the-taxation-rules-for-us-non-resident-aliens-with-respect-to-qualified)
  Note: that question is about "qualified dividends" which is irrelevant to this situation, but one of the answers there explains "portfolio interest" and "qualified interest income", which are relevant.
- [Nontaxable Types of Interest Income for Nonresident Alien Individuals](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/nontaxable-types-of-interest-income-for-nonresident-alien-individuals)

  > Nonresident aliens (NRAs) are not taxed on certain kinds of interest income as follows, per Internal Revenue Code subsections 871(i) and (h), provided that such interest income arises from one of the following sources:
  >
  > 1. A U.S. bank
  > 2. A U.S. savings and loan association
  > 3. A U.S. credit union
  > 4. A U.S. insurance company
  > 5. **Portfolio Interest** (Described in “3. Exclusions From Gross Income" – “Nonresident Aliens” - "Interest Income" and its subsection "Portfolio interest" of [Publication 519, U.S. Tax Guide for Aliens](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-publication-519))
- Bogleheads forum: [[Wiki] Bond ETF Non US resident withholding tax](https://www.bogleheads.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=281682)
- Bogleheads wiki: [Nonresident alien taxation](https://www.bogleheads.org/wiki/Nonresident_alien_taxation)

  Relevant section: *Interest distributions paid as dividends*

  > Where a US domiciled ETF receives US source interest on its holdings, and that interest would not have been taxable to a US nonresident if paid directly, the portion of the dividend attributable to this interest is 'portfolio interest'[11] and can be exempted from nonresident withholding.[12] This situation is unlikely in ETFs that hold only stocks, but will be common in bond ETFs, and any mixed-asset ETFs.
  >
  > Again, for this to occur correctly both the ETF provider and the broker need to be aware of the relevant qualified interest income (QII) regulations.
  >
  > Also, note that this exemption is particularly narrowly drawn. It does not apply to any non-US source interest or dividends that the ETF receives.[10] This means that a US domiciled ETF containing non-US bonds or non-US stocks suffers the standard 30% or lower treaty rate US tax on dividends. If the investor had instead held the ETF's assets either directly or through a non-US domiciled ETF, they would have paid no US tax.
- Bogleheads wiki: [Nonresident alien's ETF domicile decision table](https://www.bogleheads.org/wiki/Nonresident_alien%27s_ETF_domicile_decision_table)

  Relevant section: *Special exemption for interest distributions paid as dividends*

  > Where a US domiciled ETF receives US source interest on its holdings, and that interest would not have been taxable to a US nonresident if paid directly, the portion of the dividend attributable to this interest can be exempted from nonresident withholding.[1](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/nontaxable-types-of-interest-income-for-nonresident-alien-individuals) The term for this is 'portfolio interest'. It will be most common in bond ETFs. For it to occur correctly both the ETF provider and the broker need to be aware of the relevant qualified interest income (QII) regulations.
- [Tax considerations for ETF investors: Foreign withholding taxes on Fixed Income](https://www.mackenzieinvestments.com/content/dam/mackenzie/en/etfs/mi-foreign-withholding-tax-etf-sept-2020-en.pdf)
- [Vanguard 2020 Nonresident alien (NRA) layout spreadsheet](https://advisors.vanguard.com/iwe/pdf/taxcenter/2020_NRA_Layout.xls)

Comment: Who refunded the money?

Comment: @mhoran_psprep I don't know. The description of the refund is "W-8 WITHHOLDING (VTIP)".

Comment: I would like to request a re-opening of this question, so that we could write a direct answer. The alleged duplicate question is about "qualified dividends" which is irrelevant to this question although an answer there incidentally answers this question.